# supercsv compatibiltity with jdk 1.7

Tags: java, java-ee-7, supercsv

i try to found out if the library `super-csv-2.1.0` is compatible or not with the `jdk 1.7`.

Can anyone suggest me something about that?
Thankss!!!

Comment: Java 1.7 is backwards compatible to previous versions, meaning it will use version 1.6 or 1.5 compatibility mode when loading classes compiled by the corresponding JDK version. This is not the same if you want to compile 1.6 with 1.7 compiler though. If you plan to use the jar as is, you should have no issues

Comment: To me, this question seems not to fit the format expected in SO. Check the help center to see what to ask and what not. Your question should show research on the topic, or particular issue you are facing that is not trivial to solve.

Comment: thanks Ivaylo!! ok i got the message

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was compiled for Java 1.5 so is compatible with Java 1.5 and later.

(As a Super CSV committer) I actually compiled it with JDK7, using 1.5 as the maven compiler plugin's [source/target version](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html), as well as the maven [animal-sniffer](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) plugin to ensure that only Java 1.5 APIs were used.